# 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat - Monday 9pm EDT / Tuesday 1am UTC

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Tuesday the 8th at 1:00 UTC / *This is Monday the 7th at 9pm EDT.***

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=5&day=8&year=2012&hour=1&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/556/math-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

**[join the room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/556/math-town-hall-chat)**

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the final election phase.  This means that I am looking at the 7th-10th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=math.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff the page lets you select which timezone you are in (upper left of the page) so that the times you enter are according to that timezone.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff make sure you're looking at the email correction I sent out.

Comment: Based on timezone reasons, I am not sure if I will be able to make this chat.  9 p.m.-10p.m. EDT would correspond to 3a.m. - 4a.m. in my current timezone (Paris), and I do have to wake up early the next day.

Comment: @Eric: same here. Sorry I didn't respond to the scheduling e-mail. I tend to be a bit delinquent on communications during the weekend.

Comment: Indeed: 9 p.m. EDT is 2 a.m. at London, 3 a.m. at Paris, Berlin, Warsaw, 5 a.m. at Moscow...

Comment: It's $0500$ a.m. my time, I need to either stay up the whole night or get up really early in the morning and neither of them makes sense. I'll try anyway.

Comment: I'd like to thank you for the time you spent on it, I really appreciate it.

Comment: 6 people filled out the form.  The best fit were two slots that 4 people could make it - the hour I chose and the following hour.  I just go by the responses I get...I can't make everyone in an international community be available at the same time. |:

Comment: You can always fly them (and current mods) into a single room somewhere on the coast of Dubai! I am sure that Willie will not object getting the chance of going through the duty free store and buying me that bottle of Glen he owes me for a long time now. :-)